# Smart contract transactional historic data

Tags: transactions, tokens, history, smart-contract

I would like to know what are the options of keeping historical data in an smart contract and how they compare. I figure out 3 ways:

- keep variables inside the smart contract updated with the required historic data. This looks to me the easier to implement, but also the more expensive approach because the smart contract would have more logic, more processing time, more size and more data stored.
- fire relevant events, listen for then and maintain an external database. This looks to me a solution expensive to maintain as it needs a parallel centralized system.
- query the etherscan or similar block explorers. This looks to me the right approach, would release the contract of any historic data. I would not need to burden the contract with data or extra processing, I would not have to decide what I want to persist on development time, I would not have to worry about backups....

for sure I would use the third approach. My concern is that I have barely seen it mentioned or recommended getting contract historic info from block explorers. All tutorials looks to maintain variables in the contract and I wonder if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can either store historical states in your contract or output events.

Both a database and the block explorer need your events to display useful information (some debuggers can use `stack traces`, but this is not well supported yet). I would suggest that you don't create your own database, but use an existing a database. [`The Graph`](https://thegraph.com/en/) and [`Dune Analytics`](https://dune.com/browse/dashboards) are some widely used solutions to query the historical states of evm chains.

Comment: so, you mean that a normal call to a regular method in an smart contract, eg setExcludedFromMaxTransfer(address), is NOT recorded in the chain as a transaction, and would need an event to keep track of these specific things, right? So when a block explorer records transactions, what is it included then? What kind of operations are shown under Transaction tab on etherscan? What kind of operations are recorded in a blockchain?

Comment: I think there are 2 different things here: (1) one is what the blockchain stores. As it stores all transactions, meaning everything that modifies the status of the contract, all of it should be available somewhere in the blockchain if we install a custom node (2)  A different thing is what APIs (as The Graph, Dune Analytics or Infura) or explorers (as etherscan) allows us to see of this info

Comment: The transactions and their receipts are stored in the state trie:
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/data-structures-and-encoding/patricia-merkle-trie/#state-trie
All the information available to you can be found here: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2718.
In most cases, this information alone will not be sufficient to reconstruct state without executing them yourself or running an archive node

Comment: In general, the goal of blockchain is to store as little data as possible in as secure a format as possible. All data that is not necessary for security is discarded. 
This makes direct querying of the blockchain inefficient and difficult. Most projects will rely on external services to make querying more efficient. Their API has more information than a regular Ethereum Node.